# How to clip a shapefile to a bounding box?

Tags: anaconda, shapefile, ogr, geos

Any suggestions for how to clip [this shapefile](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/50m/cultural/ne_50m_admin_0_map_subunits.zip) to the appropriate bounding box? In particular, I'd like to view only these bounds: [(-105.53 , 39.9) (-104.93,40.27)]. The [site for ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html#ogr2ogr_performance) has an example fo using the `-clipdst` option that looks promising. I use [Anaconda](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/) to manage my python installs. I have GDAL installed such that `conda update gdal` produces:

```
Fetching package metadata: ..
# All requested packages already installed.
# packages in environment at /Users/<me>/anaconda:
#
gdal                      1.10.1               np18py27_2
```

Running `which ogr2ogr`

```
ogr2ogr is /Users/<me>/anaconda/bin/ogr2ogr
```

With the Natural Earth subunits files downloaded and unzipped, I run the following:

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON -clipdst -105.53 39.9 -104.93 40.27 places.json ne_10m_admin_0_map_subunits.shp
```

Unfortunately, I receive this error:

```
ERROR 6: GEOS support not enabled.
```

I've looked up this error and the suggestion [here](http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2011-September/030243.html) is to enable `geos` (a package that I installed using `conda install geos`). So I have `geos` version 3.3.3. However, I am lost as to how to enable `ogr2ogr` to access the `geos` library.

Any help is greatly appreciated. I'm not set on using `ogr2ogr` but I didn't see many alternatives.

---

### UPDATE: 2015-02-26

After reinstalling anaconda, I then installed gdal and geos. This is the current situation:

```
$ ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON -clipdst -105.53 39.9 -104.93 40.27 places.json ne_10m_admin_0_map_subunits.shp

FAILURE:
Unable to open datasource `ne_10m_admin_0_map_subunits.shp' with the following drivers.
  -> ESRI Shapefile
  -> MapInfo File
  -> UK .NTF
  -> SDTS
  -> TIGER
  -> S57
  -> DGN
  -> VRT
  -> REC
  -> Memory
  -> BNA
  -> CSV
  -> GML
  -> GPX
  -> KML
  -> GeoJSON
  -> GMT
  -> GPKG
  -> SQLite
  -> WAsP
  -> PostgreSQL
  -> PCIDSK
  -> OpenFileGDB
  -> XPlane
  -> AVCBin
  -> AVCE00
  -> DXF
  -> Geoconcept
  -> GeoRSS
  -> GPSTrackMaker
  -> VFK
  -> PGDump
  -> OSM
  -> GPSBabel
  -> SUA
  -> OpenAir
  -> PDS
  -> WFS
  -> HTF
  -> AeronavFAA
  -> EDIGEO
  -> GFT
  -> GME
  -> SVG
  -> CouchDB
  -> Idrisi
  -> ARCGEN
  -> SEGUKOOA
  -> SEGY
  -> ODS
  -> XLSX
  -> ElasticSearch
  -> PDF
  -> CartoDB
  -> SXF
```

Comment: You need to have GDAL compiled with GEOS. If Anaconda doesn't have this, then ask their user list why this is, look elsewhere for a different precompiled package, or compile your own.

Comment: @vitale232 - not yet. See update above.

Comment: @simplyclimb what OS are you running? I just tried to create a conda package with GEOS support for linux-64. I'm curious if it would resolve the issue for you.

Comment: @vitale232 - OS X 10.9.5

Comment: conda ain't easy. i still haven't got my package to install right on two machines. deps galore. I'll let you know if i can get it, and hopefully it'll solve your issues, too

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and found the solution. The solution is you must have qt libraries installed on your system.After installing qt rpm packages, install geos and re-install gdal with --with-geos option.